# How to find the number of lists in a list

Tags: r

I am trying to identify the number of lists present in a list in R.

I have a list M of length 3.

It has values [[1]] = 'a' and [[2]]='b', and [[3]]='c'.

This length can range from 1 to n.

I want to save the number of lists as an integer and store it in any variable, here it is 3 for example so that I can use it in the for loop later.

sum=lengths(M) // here if i print sum, i am getting [1] 1 1 1 , but i samiply want 3.

Can someone help me with the R code to get the value as 3.

Comment: Please share `M` in a reproducible form.

Comment: `length(list(a=1, b=2, c=3))`. It's `length()` not `lengths()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to use `length()` to count the number of list entries:

```r
# A list with three entries
a_list <- list(first = "a", second = "b", third = "c")

# The length of the list (the number of entries in the list)
a_list_length <- length(a_list)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: it returns the length of the first list in my list and not the number of lists in my list...

Comment: @felixmp, from the expected output OP mentions, I still understand OP's request as one that is answered by my answer. Without a reproduction of M it is hard to know whether I'm wrong.